# How can I run two AJAX requests simultaneously in WordPress?

Tags: ajax

Kinda stuck here working with AJAX and trying to show posts based on user interaction.  Right now I have it working where user makes a category dropdown selection and the posts load accordingly.  What I would like to do is take it one step further and populate another drop-down with subcategories based on the parent category that was selected.  View the site [here](http://99b2435c.ngrok.io/news-insights/).

**jQuery**

```
$('#ajaxFilter select').on('change', function(event) {
if(event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }
$this = $(this);
$value = this.value;
$page = $this.data('page');
$term = $this.data('term');
$qty = $this.closest('#ajaxFilter').data('paged')

    $params = {
        //Bind parameters
        'value': $value,
        'page' : $page,
        'term' : $term,
        'qty'  : $qty,
    };

    //Run the query with those parameters
    get_posts($params);
});



function get_posts($params) {
$content   = $('#ajaxPosts');
$.ajax({
    url: psc.ajax_url,
    data: {
        action: 'filter_posts',
        nonce: psc.nonce,
        params: $params
    },
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (data.status === 200) {
        $content.html(data.content);
    }
    else if (data.status === 201) {
        $content.html(data.message);    
    }
    else {
        $status.html(data.message);
    }
    },
error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $status.html(textStatus);
     }
});
```

}

**functions.php**

```
function psc_filter_posts() {
if( !isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'psc' ) )
die('Permission denied');

$value = intval($_POST['params']['value']);;
$term = sanitize_text_field($_POST['params']['term']);
$page = intval($_POST['params']['page']);
$qty  = intval($_POST['params']['qty']);

if ( $value == 0 ) : 
    $tax_qry[] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $value,
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    ];
else :
    $tax_qry[] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => $value,
    ];
 endif;

//Setup the query args for wp query
$args = [
'paged'          => $page,
'post_status'    => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => $qty,
'tax_query'      => $tax_qry
];

$qry = new WP_Query($args);

ob_start();
if ($qry->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="container">
            <?php while ($qry->have_posts()) : $qry->the_post(); ?>

            LOOP STUFF              

            <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- .container -->

    <nav class = "container mt-5 text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <?php psc_ajax_pager($qry,$page,$value); ?>
            </div><!-- .col-sm-12 -->
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </nav>

<?php $response = [
'status'=> 200,
'found' => $qry->found_posts
];
else :
$response = [
    'status'  => 201,
    'message' => 'No posts found'
];

endif;

$response['content'] = ob_get_clean();

die(json_encode($response));

}

add_action('wp_ajax_filter_posts', 'psc_filter_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_posts', 'psc_filter_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!  So I ended up just adding in a second ajax call into the function.  For some reason it's returning successful but not with a 200 response.  Anyway, it's working.  If anyone knows why it's returning an unknown response (besides 200 or 201) please share.  Thanks!

```
function get_posts($params) {
    $.ajax({
        url: psc.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'get_subcats',
            nonce: psc.nonce,
            params: $params
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (data.status === 200) {
            }
            else if (data.status === 201) {
                alert('201');
                $content.html(data.message);    
            }
            else {
                $('#subcategories').empty();
                $('#subcategories').append(data.content);
            }
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $status.html(textStatus);
        }
        });

        $.ajax({
        url: psc.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'filter_posts',
            nonce: psc.nonce,
            params: $params
        },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (data.status === 200) {
                $('#ajaxPosts').html(data.content);
            }
            else if (data.status === 201) {
                $content.html(data.message);    
            }
            else {
                $status.html(data.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $status.html(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

**functions.php**

```
function psc_subcategories() {
if( !isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'psc' ) )
die('Permission denied');

$value = intval($_POST['params']['value']);;

ob_start();

$categories=  get_categories('child_of='.$value.'&hide_empty=1');
      foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $option .= '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">';
        $option .= $cat->cat_name;
        $option .= ' ('.$cat->category_count.')';
        $option .= '</option>';
      }
    echo '<option value="-1" selected="selected">Subcategory</option>'.$option;

$response['content'] = ob_get_clean();

die(json_encode($response));

}
```